# How do I get the auto generated Id from firestore into flutter?

Tags: flutter

[auth class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1kPK.png)

[cartService class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2yy.png)

[App User class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdy8h.png)

After I sign in to the application using the email and password already authenticated by firestore, I need to get this user's auto generated id. However, even though I'm using the get loggedInAppUser variable, it is returning a null value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get current user uid. If would suggest something like this:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void getCurrentUser() {
  final User user = auth.currentUser;
  final uid = user.uid;
  print(uid);
}
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please mark it as solved, to indicate this is the right solution for other users coming across that problem.